# Managing Powershell Sessions Using Java

Tags: java, session, powershell

I want to be able to manage Powershell PSSessions using Java. For example I want to have separate Java methods for starting sessions and ending them. Is there an easy way to have these methods? I'm thinking there could be a Powershell API, or stuff like that.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "Manage sessions"? What, specifically, do you want to do?

Comment: Hello. I edited the question as feedback to your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer: No.

Longer answer: You could create one yourself, but you should try and avoid this.

PowerShell is a set of .NET types (the various [`System.Management.Automation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/powershell_mref_reference_home.aspx) namespaces), there is not even a C API. But you could wrap enough of the PowerShell types in something you could call from Java and then use that. However as you cannot run Java in the same process part of that adapter/proxy layer will need to perform inter-process communications this is not going to be an easy task.

If your requirements were to just be able to run a PSH script then you can launch a PowerShell process with the right command line, eg. to run `script.ps1`

```
%windir%\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\Powershell.exe -file path-to-script.ps1
```

By reading from standard input in the script, and controlling standard input of the child process you could pass commands to a coöperating script:

```
while (($in = [console]::in.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
    Write-Debug "Input: '$in'"
    if ($in -match '^\s*exit\s*$') { break; }
}
```